# How to debug SQL generated by db.update method?

Tags: android, sqlite, debugging, methods

I'm writing my first Android app using Eclipse, with a SQLite database. I have a d.update call which is returning a False value, but I don't understand why. Using the Eclipse debugger I can see that the sql string (below) is broadly correct, in that the table and column names are correct, but how can I see what the final SQL looks like when it gets sent to SQLite? (i.e. after the ?'s are substituted?

```
UPDATE preset_item SET preset_minutes=?,preset_desc=? WHERE _id = ?
```

Comment: `update` does not return a boolean value. Do you mean that it returns zero?

Comment: The .update method call returns False